# PHP How to remove word in string?

Tags: php, regex

Input:

> GUJARAT (24)

Output:

> GUJARAT

String Format

> State Name (State Code)

I want to remove state code with parentheses. How can I do this by using regex in PHP?

Comment: Have you made any effort to solve this problem yourself?  Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service.  Welcome to the site, by the way.

Comment: Can you have several states on same string? Like in `FOO (123) ... BAR (456)`

Answer (score 2):

**You can try this**

```
(?<=\s)(\(.*\))
```

> Explanation

- `(?<=\s)` - Positive look behind. Matches `\s` (a white space).
- `(\(.*\))` - Matches `( some random text)`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uloYw4/1)

Comment: It could fail if there are several states on the same string, like in `GUJARAT (24) OTHER (14)`. Not specified by requirements, though. Anways an ungreedy star could be a nice addition

Comment: @Julio Yeah  but he specified string format in question. so i wrote according to that. Btw thanks for suggestion :)

Answer (score 1):

Using RegEx

```
$text="GUJARAT (24)"
$statename=preg_replace("/\([^)]+\)/","",$text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one too.

```
 $text="GUJARAT (24)";
 $statename= preg_replace("/[(][0-9]*[)]/","",$text);
 echo $statename;
```

Comment: That `{1}` seems to be unneded

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't want to use regex you can also use simple strpos and substr.
This is a lighter way to do it than using regex (less meory useage).
The code finds the `(` and removes everything one step behind and forward.

```
$arr = ["GUJARAT (24)", "State Name (State Code)"];

foreach($arr as $val){
    echo substr($val, 0, strpos($val, "(")-1) . "\n";    
}
// GUJARAT
// State Name
```

https://3v4l.org/IdvAI